# How can I implement immutable builds while using "rebase and merge" in a github repo?

Tags: git, docker, github, github-actions, immutability

I am trying to implement a CI/CI pipeline with immutable builds. Everything is deployed to GCR and GCP Cloud Run. The way the pipeline works right now is this:

- When a PR is opened, synchronized, reopened or edited: In the workflow, a docker image is built with the checked out code, tagged with `${{github.sha}}`, then pushed to GCR. Next, the cloud run service is deployed with the docker image that was just built and pushed to GCR. It is referenced by `${{github.sha}}`. This is all done in one project, but to the `dev` target. The trigger for this workflow:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
      - edited
    branches:
      - main
```

This works fine, but I am having trouble figuring out how to use the same built image to deploy the service to `test` and `prod`. The main problem is the way we merge PRs. When a PR is approved and ready to be merged, we can only use the **Rebase and Merge** option. Every other option is disabled to make sure the commit history on `main` is linear and preserved.

I do have workflows for the `test` and `prod` targets. The one for `prod` is not an issue since it is triggered manually. The one for `test` is empty since I don't know what the best way to implement the explained strategy.

I have already tried referencing the same image like this in the workflow:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: main

# other steps

- name: Tag Docker image for test
        run: |
          gcloud container images add-tag \
            gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/dev-${{ matrix.app }}:$SHORT_SHA \
            gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/test-${{ matrix.app }}:$SHORT_SHA
```

`$SHORT_SHA` is a custom variable that simply stores the first 7 characters of the `${{github.sha}}.

This does not work, and if I understand correctly it's because when code is checked out in the workflow, it creates a merge commit sha. Since these are two different workflows, I assume the SHAs are different too, which results in a 404 since there is no container with the tag.

What should I do?